# How to get VirtualKeyCode value from System.Windows.Input.Key in C#?

Tags: c#, key

I know that similar questions are present on stack overflow, but they are not helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by a key, if not a virtual key code?

Comment: Code, where's the code? I need the code! What have you tried?

Comment: This question is not helpful.

Comment: an amazing first post

Comment: I mean static type - Key. I need only to know how to convert this type, so i didn't post code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop.virtualkeyfromkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method.

Also I recommend you to [read how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), that will be helpful for your next question.

Comment: ...assuming OP is asking about WPF keys, which may or may not be the case.